# Disqus API in iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, api, disqus

Is it possible to hook-up natively (in Objective-C/CocoaTouch) to the Disqus API (e.g., not using the WebView)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It struck me that there's no disqus library for iOS, so I made a simple wrapper myself. Currently, it's only for viewing and posting comments.

Feel free to use it : [Disquser](https://github.com/ixnixnixn/IADisquser).

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Disqus, but their docs look pretty straightforward, you'd make an NSURLRequest/Connection to something like `http://disqus.com/api/3.0/trends/listThreads.json?api_key=API_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE` and it would return JSON, that you could parse with something like SBJSON (you'd be left with an NSDictionary, and the data would be an array at `objectForKey:@"response"`

http://docs.disqus.com/help/52/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Also, this document looks semi-promising: http://appworks.radeeccles.com/programming/disqus-api-objective-c/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library. This is what you are looking for https://github.com/moqod/disqus-ios